# Traits, OO way of including functions?

Tags: php, traits

I can't really think of traits anything other than an Object Oriented way of `include/require`.

If I want a set of functions that are not related to any particular class or are so common that can be used with several classes I put them in a `php` file and `include` or `require` it in the class I want to use them in.

`include '/path/to/a/file.php';`

With traits I could do something like:

```
trait Common {

    // common functions

}
```

and use it in any class with `use Common;`

So am I right, thinking of traits as just the Object Oriented way of good old `include/require`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PHP docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php include causes the scope of functions and classes to be global whereas a trait only gets scope within the class. That is probably the biggest difference.